# Fastest Filter Peformance for Array of Objects

Tags: powershell

I am using the Import-CSV cmdlet to load a list of ~180k items containing 6 columns.  Because of the size of this list Where-Object cmdlet is not very performant since each call to it will iterate the entire list. As such I am desperate to find another way to make filtering much quicker.  I am always filtering on just one of the columns then updating another column in the resulting filtered list. Is there something I am overlooking that may help? Such as indexing the search column or converting to some other object?  Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: You'll get better answers if you post your code or some examples of the conditions and transforms you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the whole list once, and do each conditional check and relevant substitution on the current item.

```
$myRows | ForEach-Object -Process {
    if ($_.prop1 -eq $condition1) {
        $_.prop4 = $newValue
    }

    if ($_.prop2 -eq $condition2) {
        $_.prop6  -eq $someOtherValue
    }
}
```

An even better approach might be to write your own function that encapsulates the transform logic and supports the pipeline. If your columns are always supposed to be the same you can even bind them by property value. Then you'd basically just do:

```
Import-Csv -Path $myCsv | Convert-MyRow
```

Comment: Excellent idea! Thanks for breaking my mental block!